# How to display numeric value 0.0 as 0.00 as the query result

Tags: ruby, postgresql, number-formatting

The value saved in the database is `0.0` as numeric data type.How to display the numeric value 0.0 as 0.00 as the query result?

Comment: select cast(0.0 as decimal(18,2))

Comment: Why? `select 0.0 = 0.00; t`

Comment: Your question in unclear to me. When you search for records with the value `0.00` PostgreSQL will return the record with the `0.0` value. Because zero equals zero, no matter how many additional zeros (`0.0 == 0.00`). Why do you care about the number of zero digits after the decimal point? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I thought there was a way, as I need that format to display in the frontend

Comment: @Gonza your database stores the data, your frontend displays the data. Likewise, the frontend should be responsible for formatting the data, not the database.

Comment: @Gonza since you mention a "frontend" – are you using Rails? If so, have a look at the [`formatting`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#formatting) extensions as well as [`ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html)

Comment: Yes, but there are cases of cases, in this case the backend sent  a block of code formatted as html as a response, so every case is totally different.  There are 3 values that return the active record relation  with numeric data type in some case come as 0.0. I'm going to check if it is possible to use the number_to_currency as I need to adpt to the code.

Comment: this colution SELECT to_char(0.0, '90.99');  from below have been useful for one value, I'm going to check what is happing with  the 2  other values.

Answer (score 4):

Formatting a value for being rendered in a specific way in the frontend is not a concern of the database.

Instead, use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-25) to control how the float should be formatted in the frontend. In your case, when you want to render the float with two digits, you can use this formatting rule:

```
float = 0.0
"%0.2f" % float
#=> "0.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT to_char(0.0, '90.99');
```

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) for documentation.

Comment: I thinks this works, but it allows only 2 main digits, how to allow any of them like: 324.01  or  9.23, or 0.00, or 3212.98 ?

Comment: I think you would need to do `99990.99` or something like that. Not sure how to do an arbitrary number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on your datastore. Some will support what you want, and some won't.

First comment by [Error_2646](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5662005/error-2646) got it right, at least with postgres. Something like `select cast(0.0 as decimal(18,2))` will indeed work. Or `as numeric`, as they're equivalent. The first number (`18` in this case) is the scale, or the maximum number of digits left of the decimal point. The second (`2`) is the precision, or the number of digits returned to the right of the decimal point.

The arguments that it "shouldn't" be done strike me as sort of hollow. Sometimes there's more than one front end. Sometimes the database is just more efficient.

Alternatively, and perhaps more efficiently, the data could be stored with a numeric/decimal with the required precision in the first place. Then you wouldn't need to cast anything in your query.